# Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server. [Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)]

Tags: apache, debian

Tried all alternatives still couldn't resolve. The following error i'm getting:-
Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server. [Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)]

This is my default file placed under /etc/apache2/sites-enabled. The media folder is path to my remove-able disk drive named XYZ.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@loclahost

DocumentRoot /media/XYZ/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /media/XYZ/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all


</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Comment: Can you post the permissions for the /media/XYZ/www folder?

Comment: i tried giving read and write permission to group user and owner. still not works.

Comment: Try testing the file permissions.  Run `sudo -u www-data cat /media/XYZ/www/*some file*`

Comment: it says permission denied

Comment: how to permit this operation

Comment: Where is your `</VirtualHost>` tag

Comment: You'll need to add read permissions so the www-data user can access those files.  Give everyone read permissions.

Comment: how to give these permission. I tried giving through gui but it seems it doesn't reflect?

Comment: i change the permission it automatically becomes none for www folder in XYZ

Answer (score 0):

default file in sites enabled directory is fine and working with virtualhost.It was permission related issue.Though permissions were granted but it was not being updated.
The problem was caused as filetype was ntfs and after formatting to ext4 format and giving permission to directory. problem got resolved.

Conclusion.
If facing such issue check file format and check permissions to directory are updated.Thanks.